# Pagination based on parameters (OFFSET FETCH NEXT)

Tags: sql-server

How I display All data when parameters are null,

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 5
        ,@PageNo  INT = 2

SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY [NO]
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: `ISNULL(@PageSize * (@PageNo - 1), 0)`, `ISNULL(@PageSize, 2147483647)` is one way to try (assuming your table really doesn't have more than 2 billion rows), but I have no idea if the engine optimizes this efficiently. If it doesn't, your only recourse is separate queries.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I just changed the same with you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this

```
SET @PageSize = ISNULL(@PageSize, 2147483647) -- max int
SET @PageNo = ISNULL(@PageNo, 1)

SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY [NO]
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I is ok, but my code is a big query, so I want to manage it in one query.